# Как вытащить форму из области уведомление(трей)

Tags: c#

Есть основная форма, которую я могу сворачивать-разворачивать в(из) области уведомлений(трей).

```
private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
            {
                notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
                notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(3000);
                this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
            }
        }

        public void notifyIcon1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            this.ShowInTaskbar = true;
            notifyIcon1.Visible = false;
        }
```

Стоит задача из другого класса "вытаскивать" программу из трея.

Пробую вот так, но почему то оно не отображается

```
Form1 frm = new Form1();
frm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
frm.ShowInTaskbar = true;
frm.notifyIcon1.Visible = false;
frm.TopMost = true;
```

Comment: Очевидно, вы создаёте _новый_ экземпляр формы. А надо использовать ссылку на уже существующую.

Comment: как вариант передавать объект Form1 в конструктор формы Form2 и использовать его там `var form2 = new Form2(this);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я вам предлагаю разбить логику на отдельные части и работать с их ссылками, а не созданием объекта отдельно.

К примеру мы создадим новый класс, который будет отвечать исключительно за работу с `NotifyIcon`, я назову его `NotifyHelper`. В этом классе мы пропишем стартовые значения (иконку) и методы вывода нужных уведомлений, то есть получаем что то вроде этого:

```
public class NotifyHelper
{
    NotifyIcon notify;
    public NotifyHelper(NotifyIcon notify)
    {
        this.notify = notify;
        this.notify.Icon = SystemIcons.Application;
    }

    public NotifyHelper Visible(bool visible = true)
    {
        notify.Visible = visible;
        return this;
    }

    public void Show(string title, string text, int timeout = 3000, ToolTipIcon icon = ToolTipIcon.Info)
    {
        if (notify == null) return;
        notify.ShowBalloonTip(timeout, title, text, icon);
    }

    public void ShowWarn(string text, string title = "Внимание") => 
        Show(title, text, icon: ToolTipIcon.Warning);

    public void ShowInfo(string text, string title = "Информация") =>
        Show(title, text);
}
```

Теперь у стартовой формы пропишем инициализацию данного класса, я лично сделаю прям в конструкторе:

```
NotifyHelper NotifyHelper;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    NotifyHelper = new NotifyHelper(notifyIcon1).Visible();
}
```

Все, теперь мы можем с этим классом работать где угодно, достаточно передать ссылку.
Для примера я создам на первой форме две кнопки, при нажатие первой мы выведем обычное уведомление, а при нажатие 2-й мы откроем 2-ю форму.

[image: Form1]

- Первый обработчик пусть вызывает `.ShowInfo()` из нашего вспомогательного класса:

  ```
  private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) => 
      NotifyHelper.ShowInfo("Объявление из первого окна!");
  ```
- А второй пусть открывает новую форму, передавая через конструктор `NotifyHelper`:

  ```
  private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) => 
      new Form2(NotifyHelper).Show();
  ```

Все, с первой формой закончили, осталось подготовить чуть вторую:

- Принимаем через конструктор вспомогательный класс:

  ```
  NotifyHelper NotifyHelper;

  public Form2(NotifyHelper notifyHelper)
  {
      InitializeComponent();
      NotifyHelper = notifyHelper;
  }
  ```
- Ну и для примера добавим одну кнопку на форуму и в ее обработчике клика вызываем нужный метод из вспомогательного класса:

  ```
  private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) => 
      NotifyHelper.ShowWarn("Произошла ошибка!");
  ```

Вот собственно и все.
Мы "завернули" `NotifyIcon` в свой класс, который отвечает только за него и дальше просто вызываем нужные методы, не затрагивая всю форму и что то еще. Вам остается снабдить класс тем функционалом, который нужен (сменить иконку в трее, показать может другое уведомление, вывести окно из трея и так далее).

[image: Result]